# Get Query String value with Jquery, AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

HI,

i need to pass id=2 while calling the action method ? How can i pass id value to controller

http://localhost:52391/Campaign/Edit/2

{Controller}=Product
{ActionMethod}=Action
{id} =2

```
 function getProductDetails() {           
           var link = '**/Product/Details?callback=?**';                      
            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                data: {},
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "doextrawork"
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var link = '/Product/Details?callback=?';
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    data: { id: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>' },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "doextrawork"
 });
```

Comment: data: { id: 2 },
i need to pass id dynamically from URL

Comment: @Aabb, then try like this: `data: { id: '<%= ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>' }`.

Answer (score 0):

simply pass a json object with your id as a property.

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    data: {
        id: 2
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "doextrawork"
});
```

Comment: data: { id: 2 },
i need to pass id dynamically from URL how can i